# Regarding passing a complete object into http Get request to Spring Controller

Tags: angularjs, spring

Have a AngularJS service calling the http Get and passing user object as an argument.

```
 $http.get(urls.USER_SERVICE_API_LOGIN + user)
                    .then(...
```

And my Spring controller is as below-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/{user}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> findUserByUserNameAndPasswordForLogin(@PathVariable(value = "user") User user) { \\\ methos definition}
```

so getting exception when calling Spring controller saying "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'model.User'" where user is my Java object and i understand AngularJS is trying to pass everything as a String. so what is the solution for this please?

Comment: You won't be able to do this using HTTP GET method, either you need to use POST or PUT for this.

Comment: How could a whole object be part of the path of a URL? A request sending a password should never use GET. You don't want the password to be part of the URL and be stored in logs for anyone to see. Use a POST.

Comment: so if i want to pass userName and password only how to pass that -

$http.get(urls.USER_SERVICE_API_LOGIN + userName,password), will this work.